# form_tag , form_remote_tag - action not being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my new Team form, user can select players, from a select listbox, to associate with team and can also create new players. Clicking on the 'New Player' button opens a popup form with the following code

When i use the form tag (see below), clicking on the submit button uses the correct action.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "teams", :action => "createPlayers") do %>
<label>Player Name:</label> <%= text_field_tag(:name, nil) %></span>
<%= submit_tag("Create New Player") %>
```

However am planning on using ajax to update the select list for players. When i use `'form_remote_tag'` instead of `'form_tag'` and i click on the submit button, the 'createPlayers' action is not called. In fact nothing happens..

I would be grateful if someone can tell me why using 'form_remote_tag' does not call the 'createPlayers' action when the submit button is pressed.

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Cheers

Comment: using firebug or equivalent, can you verify that the post is being initiated from the browser, and that it is failing? This should give you your error in the response.

Comment: Got it -

Instead of

<%= form_remote_tag (:controller => "teams", :action => "createPlayers") do %>

I used:

<% form_remote_tag :url => {:controller => 'teams', :action => 'createPlayers'} do %>... cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { :controller => 'xyz', :action => :you method } do %> 
<%=text_field_tag : %>
<%= submit_tag "" %> 
<% end %> 
something like that
```